# Looping an R dataframe to generate conditional Strings

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe that has 11 tickers in it. I need to run a loop or equivalent  and dynamically generate a string in each iteration with a maximum of 3 tickers separated by a + sign in each iteration. How can I do that?

```
all_stockticks <-   
data.frame(symbol=c("AAPL","GOOG","MSFT","C","JPM","GS","INFY","WIT","CTSH","V","MA")
)

In iteration-1 output would be str=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT
In iteration-2 output would be str=C+JPM+GS
In iteration-3 output would be str=INFY+WIT+CTSH
In iteration-4 output would be str=V+MA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rollapply` from the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(all_stockticks, 3, by = 3, paste, collapse = "+", partial = TRUE, 
            align = "left")
```

giving:

```
     symbol          
[1,] "AAPL+GOOG+MSFT"
[2,] "C+JPM+GS"      
[3,] "INFY+WIT+CTSH" 
[4,] "V+MA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the IRanges way:

```
library(IRanges)
symbolList <- relist(as.character(all_stockticks$symbol),
                     breakInChunks(nrow(all_stockticks), 3))
unstrsplit(symbolList, "+")
```

The `breakInChunks` function generates an object representing a partitioning. We call `relist` to form the list that would have had such a partitioning, and finally `unstrsplit` (intuitively the inverse of `strsplit`) to collapse the strings. Here, all iteration is in native code, so it should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 n <- nrow(all_stockticks)
 c(by(all_stockticks[,1], as.numeric(gl(n,3,n)), FUN=paste,collapse="+"))
              1                2                3                4 
 #"AAPL+GOOG+MSFT"       "C+JPM+GS"  "INFY+WIT+CTSH"           "V+MA"
```